# For-Else Statement with Multiple If-Break Conditions

Tags: python, for-else

I wrote a simple python module that returns the prime numbers up to a given N, using a bool flag `is_prime` as follows:

```
def generate_primes_up_to(M):
    n = 2
    primes = []    
    while n <= M:
        is_prime = True
        for p in primes:
            if p**2 > n: break
            if n % p == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime: primes.append(n) 
        n += 1
    return primes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_primes_up_to(100)
```

which outputs:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Now, this is actually an ideal case for using the `for-else` construct, since the number `n` is prime only if no `break`s occurred in the `for` loop. Thus, I changed the function into:

```
def generate_primes_up_to(M, flag='nonumpy'):
    n = 2
    primes = []    
    while n <= M:
        for p in primes:
            if p**2 > n: break
            if n % p == 0: break
        else: primes.append(n) 
        n += 1
    return primes
```

but now the code outputs:

```
[2, 5, 27]
```

I don't understand why the `if p**2 > n: break` expression is interfering with the flow of the `for-else` clause. If I remove that line the code yields the right output again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition causing the issue is -

```
if p**2 > n: break
```

Lets take an example - `7` , when we are checking if 7 is prime or not , we have already found out that - `[2,3,5]` are primes, the above condition breaks the `for` loop, when we check `3` as `3**2` = `9` which is greater than `7` .

Remove that condition and it works fine (Though its very slow).

In the original loop (without the for-else construct) , it worked because in that condition you just broke out of the loop, you did not change the flag `is_prime` .

---

With the `for..else` construct, what happens is that, the `else` part is only executed when we exit the loop without using `break` statement.

But in the case of the above condition , we use `break` statement and hence `else` part is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `next`:

```
def generate_primes_up_to(M):
    n = 2
    primes = []
    while n <= M:
        if next((False for p in primes if not n % p), True):
            primes.append(n)
        n += 1

    return primes
```